# Creating back-end database on cloud

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, azure

I have created an Xamarin Android apps which uses Google Vision API. Now, I want to create a cloud base database to retrieve some information. For example, I will get some 'brand name' from Google Vision API and on the base of that result i want to display some description about that particular brand and those description will be stored on back-end database.

I have created mobile service account on Azure Portal, tried few tutorials but could n't get any idea how to connect app with back end data.
Any links of suggestion will be great help to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, I will get some 'brand name' from Google Vision API and on the base of that result i want to display some description about that particular brand and those description will be stored on back-end database.

Per my understanding, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started#create-an-azure-mobile-app-backend) to create your Azure Mobile App backend, then download the quick start Xamarin.Android app for getting started with azure mobile apps.

For C# backend, you could follow this [tutorial](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/) about adding a SQL Table Controller for expose the table data to your client. Also, you could build your custom Web API, for more details, you could refer to [Custom HTTP Endpoints](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/).

For client app, you could leverage [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) for connecting with your azure mobile app backend. For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library) about working with managed client for Azure Mobile Apps.

Additionally, for authentication / authorization between your client app and your azure mobile backend, you could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-auth).

Answer (score 0):

You should develop the API services to connect with database.

database -> Restful API -> Mobile

Comment: thats what i am trying to do but not getting proper direction, could u suggest any appropriate links. Or more specific steps that need to be done.
Thanks

Comment: @KopilaPanth For Example, you can use C# to retrieve data from database first. And you can using Asp.net MVC Framework to make a web based restful api(display JSON api on web page). And deploy the web to Azure WebApp. And you can access the API by Url like http://api.test.com/login . And your Xamarin Android app can access this API you build.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use a [mBAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service) if you don't want to write your back-end from the begining. That would allow you to focus on the front-end.